# Why would only the last node fail to write to an XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml

I just have a quick question about writing a setting to a node in my xml file for some reason all my other settings save but this one and the value I am trying to save is (ListingRid=1+),(PictureCount=1+) in my code textBoxQuery.Text contains (ListingRid=1+),(PictureCount=1+)

Example XML

```
<setting name="SearchQuery" serializeAs="String">
<value></value>
</setting>
```

And here is the code I call can anyone tell me if the value may have invalid characters maybe and that is why the setting is not saved?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//setting"))
{
    if (node.OuterXml.Contains("SearchQuery"))
{
    node.LastChild.InnerText = textBoxQuery.Text;
}
doc.Save(path); //I have this in there at the end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to call the actual node attribute by the value instead of using the OuterXml.Contains this seems to have fixed the issue.

```
            if (node.Attributes["name"].Value == ("SearchQuery"))
             node.LastChild.Innertext = textBoxQuery.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no values for textBoxQuery.Text that are invalid in this context

`node.LastChild.InnerText = textBoxQuery.Text`

Because InnerText escapes the values when they are set. This is the difference between `InnerXml` and `InnerText`

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget this?

```
doc.Save(path);
```

Comment: hmm the OP says that *all my setting save but this one* so that shouldn't be it...

Comment: Unless he is calling save for the other settings but not this one.  But I see he edited his post and added it.